# Problem with image base64 encoding: images are 'quite never' displayed in the created html

Tags: objective-c, image, base64, gdata-api, google-docs-api

I build an html doc by encoding images with base64.
Then, I upload the html on google docs, but images are 'quite never' displayed.
The encoding is right: for example, I use [this](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) to do the image encoding and then I use it in the `img` tag for the `src` attribute, changing properly the data type

```
<img src='data:image/gif;base64,<IMG_ENCODING>' />
```

or

```
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,<IMG_ENCODING>' />
```

or

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,<IMG_ENCODING>' />
```

**EDIT**

I think the problem is tied to compression. I tried to use

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.0f)];
```

And some of the images (that before aren't displayed) are displayed. But other images aren't. I don't know if there is a limit to the length on the base64 string on gdocs.

Is there a way to compress the base64 string before sending it to the server? or?

Any hint is greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

None of your images are displayed or only some ? And if only some, then only the small ones are displayed ? Because if you answer yes to all then the problem is that your files are to large to be used as base64 encoded sources for the image tags. The browser reads that as a url and there is a limit to the length of a url (about 7-8kb max)

Comment: Thanks. Only some images, but not always the small ones. A google engineer wrote to me that a base64 image cannot be more than 2mb in size and nor more than 2500x2500 pixels, but my whole doc was about 4kb with images about 320x480. At the end, I uploaded images separately.